# VIews Embed View change pager Id

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I am using Views 7.x.3.14. My Parent views calls another view through views PHP field, I have done it through views_embed_view. So far all good both the views render properly.

Now when it comes to pager, I want to dynamically change the pager id of the embedded view. I have implemented `views_pre_view` which changes the pager id for my embedded view, but in this case parent views pager has disappeared.

below is my hook code-

```
$pager_options = $view->display_handler->get_option('pager');
$view->display['block']->handler->options['pager']['options']['id'] = $rowCount++;
$view->display_handler->set_option('pager', $pager_options);
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why do you want to change pager id ?

Comment: Bcoz i have render my view using views_Embed_view and it appear inside a listing parent views multiple times.

Comment: Rather my views is called in PHP field which has listing. e.g. Article content type listing view with a PHP (using views_php module) field which calls a view to list down comments on that node. hope this helps in giving you an idea of what exactly i have implemented?